# SQL Server 2017 SYSUTCDATETIME(), where is it derived from?

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2017

I have a stored procedure that inserts as a value in a column SYSUTCDATETIME().

I live in Hastings in the UK (pretty close to the meridian line) so we are currently on British Summer Time (one hour ahead of GMT or UTC).  Ergo when I ran this procedure at 19.46 last night I would have expected the procedure to have recorded 18.46 as the UTC value in the relevant field in the underlying table.  Instead I was surprised to see the value recorded as being 18.06, forty minutes adrift of what I had expected.

This makes me wonder if SQL Server is in fact using the internet to determine UTC time (my computer always records it's location as being considerably further west that it actually is which is connected with my ISP's location(I assume)). If this is indeed the case then I need to find a way of getting SQL Server to calculate UTC time from the local machine rather that using the internet as an anomaly like this could actually lead to some very serious consequences.

Does anyone know what SQL Server actually uses as its source for calculating UTC time, and if it is the internet (when available) how to force it to use the local machine on which it is running?

Comment: What was the computer time at that stage?

Comment: 19.46 as stated, hence my confusion and curiosity as to where 18.06 came from

Comment: Hmm, that's strange - is this happening all the time? E.g. if you call `SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME()`, what do you get, and if you call `SELECT GETUTCDATE()` what does that give you back?